# why do I need to specify all files for karma config even if they are loaded with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, karma-runner

I have the following directory structure:

```
--app
  |---dots
  |    |---some.js
  |
  |---entry.js
  |---bootstrap.js
  |---karma.conf.js
  |---test-main.js
  |---test
      |---sampleSpec.js
```

Here is my `sampleSpec` dependencies:

```
define(["app/bootstrap", "app/dots/some"], function () {}]
```

So as I understand it I load `bootstrap` and `some` files into browser using requirejs. However, depending on whether I specify `dots/*` folder in my `karma.conf.js` file the karma server succeeds or fails to resolve `dots/some.js` file. What I mean is if I specify the following `pattern: 'app/**/*.js'` in `karma.conf.js`:

```
files: [
  'test-main.js',
  {pattern: 'app/**/*.js', included: false},
  {pattern: 'test/*Spec.js', included: false}
],
```

The `dots/some.js` file is loaded into browser, if I specify like this `pattern: 'app/*.js'` karma server returns `404` - file not found. Why is it so? Why should `karma` care about the path if I load it using `requirejs`?

Comment: Because it has to create the routing to serve them when required. Karma creates a web server that serves the files you want to test: if you don't load them at startup you still want to reach them later, that's why it wants to know where they are.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but still it's unclear. Is it because how routing is working inside nodejs (I assume karma is using NodeJs)? Because otherwise karma could easily extend the path from the root. And does webserver serve files under my project's root? It doesn't copy it them anywhere?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you fire karma up, what karma does is:

- It does some pre-process job
- It creates a webpage where your web assets are loaded (css, js, etc...)
- It creates a webserver to serve your assets

The webserver needs to know where you have your own assets and if you want to serve them straight from the page or load them later.

In your karma config file you have several options to configure how you want to load them:

```
...
files: [
   'test-main.js',
   {pattern: 'app/**/*.js', included: true, watched: false, served: true},
   ...
],

proxies: {
  '/img/': 'http://localhost:8080/base/test/images/'
}
```

In the `files` array you can put all the resources that you want to be included, watched and served.

If you want instead to use a custom URL (say you have a specific route in your app) you can tell karma how to reflect that custom URL to a static URL or simply to to map it (say you're using a third party service).

**If a file is not mapped there karma won't serve it, so when you're requiring it your request will have an `HTTP 404` response.**
Karma accepts also regexp patterns (minimatch strings) as routes - as specified in the documentation - so your `app/**/*.js` will match any js files within `app` at any level, while `app/*.js` will only match JS files strictly inside the `app` folder.

In case of a proxy, say you're interested to serve images, karma sets up a static server where `http://localhost:8080/base` maps your project root directory.

For a full explanation have a look at the [karma documentation](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/files.html).

Comment: thanks, so what you're basically saying is that because I can create a custom URL to request `dots/some.js` file, `karma server` is not going to automatically map it to `app/dots/some.js`? Do you have a source code location to check out this mapping in karma's sources?

Comment: No, I'm saying you have always to say to karma where your files/assets are. And above there's how to say that.

Comment: I think `proxy: []` is an older syntax? I'm seeing `proxies` in the current documentation page. If it is outdated, you might want to update your answer with new one. @MarcoL

Comment: Good spot. I've updated the answer here to have `proxies` as objects. It has always been an object, I just misspelled it.

Comment: why a specific sequence of files is required while performing karma jasmine in angularjs?